# gfortran returns `*.f90: No such file or directory` when compiling multiple files

Tags: macos, bash, fortran, sh, gfortran

I have a folder with 354 .f90 modules (and the main file). In the readme this is suggested:

> The best approach is to unzip the archive `source.zip` extracting all
>   354 program files into a directory of your choice.  Then you can
>   compile with the command
>
> ```
> gfortran *.f90 -o app.exe
> ```

I'm on Mac so i installed gfortran but doing the command written above doesn't work:

```
gfortran: *.f90: No such file or directory
```

So I suppose that a bash script is needed (or at least a makefile).
I'm not used to doing this so what should I do? Does there exist some automatic makefile generator?

Comment: Are you sure, you are in the right directory?

Comment: Sure. In facts if I write the entire first file name it works. Forgot to say I'm on Mac OSX Snow Leopard. Don't know If it's important.

Comment: So I guess "ls *.f90" gives you all the files? Maybe "gfortran $(ls *.f90) -o app.exe" would work? Strange...

Comment: It works for me.   That is "gfortran *.f90", and on a Mac.   Not with your 354 files but with some others.  Why is gfortran seeing "*.f90" and not a list of files?  What shell are you using?

Comment: @haraldkl if i write "ls *.f90" same error. If i just write "ls" it gives me all the files in the directory. I'm using the classic bash Terminal on OSX.

Comment: I'm an idiot!!!! the file extension is not *.f90 but **.F90** with capital letters. Sorry men for the stupidity!! :(

with 
    gfortran -o executable *.F90
it worked. =.=

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was just a stupidity issue. The extension of the files was **.F90** and not **.f90**. With:

```
gfortran -o app *.F90
```

it worked.